# Unable to use register_google in R

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to create simple K-means clustering by using ggmap in R.

I ran:

```
if(!requireNamespace("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
```

which is a recommendation from github/ggmap (https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap).

However, when I try to use

```
register_google(key='MyAPI')
```

R keeps giving error of not being able to find function register_google().
The ggmap is already installed and loaded.

I checked from various sources (eg: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/143), which suggests restarting R session. Still, the function register_google() does not work.
My code looks like this:

```
library(ggmap)
data14=read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/uber-tlc-foil-response/master/uber-trip-data/uber-raw-data-apr14.csv")
register_google(key = "MyAPI") **This part does not work for me**
NYCMap <- get_map('New York',maptype = 'roadmap', zoom=10)
ggmap(NYCMap) + geom_point(aes(x=Lon[], y =Lat[]), data=data14)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Please feel free to let me know if you need more information.

EDIT: output and error from R

```
> install.packages("ggmap")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/ggmap_2.6.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4565845 bytes (4.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.4 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/2k/y418d7qs7jdbwzyv6q4sz3gc0000gn/T//RtmpmTPB4Y/downloaded_packages
> if(!requireNamespace("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
> devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
Downloading GitHub repo dkahle/ggmap@tidyup
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/2k/y418d7qs7jdbwzyv6q4sz3gc0000gn/T/RtmpmTPB4Y/remotes87187e0df6f3/dkahle-ggmap-4dfe516/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘ggmap’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) :
     unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018g.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory ‘ggmap/.github’
─  looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
─  building ‘ggmap_2.7.904.tar.gz’ (696ms)

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018g.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘ggmap’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.4
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.4
* DONE (ggmap)
> library(ggmap)
> register_google(key = "MyAPI")
Error in register_google(key = "MyAPI") : 
  could not find function "register_google"
```

Comment: I see code to install `ggmap`, but I don't see code to load the package. You didn't explain what you meant by "activated in my environment". Perhaps this is yet another instance a question answered by  R-FAQ 7.30?

Comment: Sorry that I did not make it clear, because google requires API to use their map, the ggmap package requires installation directly from GitHub, hence the first two lines in the beginning. I also load the package right after installing by using library(ggmap) but the register_google() command still does not work.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are receiving? Do you have a Google API key? or are you using "MyAPI" as the key?  When posting the error message be sure to remove your API key so is it not publicly displayed.

Comment: Hi Dave2e, I added the exact output and error that I got in R. Please take a look. I already activated my Google API key and enable billing on Google Maps Platform. I put MyAPI because I don't want to include the exact key.

Comment: The first lines of your post indicates installing ver 2.6.1 while you need to install version 2.7.904 from Github. Try running `sessionInfo()` to verify the correct version of ggmap is loaded.  You should not run `install.packages("ggmap")` since this is installing the incorrect version.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, that does not seem to work. I used sessionInfo() to check and it showed correct version 2.7.904.

Comment: Sorry, to hear that.  The "could not find function" error would indicate the incorrect version of ggmap is installed, but the SessionInfo says otherwise.  Other than performing a fresh install of R and `install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")`, I am out of suggestions to help.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I am using macOS el-capitan.

Below are the steps I've taken to resolve:

- confirm you've removed the CRAN version of ("ggmap") '2.6.1'. via remove.packages("ggmap")
- once removed you will also need to confirm the removal of ("tibble") using the above method.
- devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
- you will be prompted to install tibble, select 'Y'
- Install should begin
- if asked "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" select no

Answer (score 0):

I used this and worked.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
library(ggmap)
library(devtools)
```

Then you can use `register_google()`

Answer (score 0):

```
ggmap::register_google(key = google_api, write = TRUE)
```

if ggmap is already installed and R yet cannot find it, one possible cause is the function 'register_google' is hidden by another homonymous function from another packages.
Adding "ggmap" make the call explicit